# WPF Read cells from DataGrid with list

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am writing a code in C# with WPF and I want to read the Item/Value of the selected Cell/Row.
Here is the code behind the DataGrid!

Thanks and Greets!

```
class Zeiten
{
    public string Linie { get; set; }
    public string Von { get; set; }
    public string Abf { get; set; }
    public string Nach { get; set; }
    public string Ank { get; set; }

    public Zeiten(string Linie, string Von, string Abf, string Nach, string Ank)
    {
        this.Linie = Linie;
        this.Von = Von;
        this.Abf = Abf;
        this.Nach = Nach;
        this.Ank = Ank;
    }
}

var items = new List<Zeiten>();
items.Add(new Zeiten(linie, Properties.Settings.Default.StarName, result.ToString("H:mm"), ziel, result2.ToString("H:mm")));
ZeitList.ItemsSource = items;
```

Answer (score 0):

To work with WPF, I suggest you to use MVVM, and use MVVM Light Toolkit to make things easy to you.

But if you want to keep using code-behind, you can define SelectionChanged event in DataGrid.

So in XAML you must have SelectionChanged defined, like that:

```xml
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" SelectionChanged="Selector_OnSelectionChanged"/>
```

And in you code-behind you must have the code for this event, like that:

```
private void Selector_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = (DataGrid)sender;
    Zeiten selectedItem = (Zeiten)grid.SelectedItem;
    MessageBox.Show("Selected value");
    MessageBox.Show("Linie: " + selectedItem.Linie);
    MessageBox.Show("Von: " + selectedItem.Von);
    MessageBox.Show("Abf: " + selectedItem.Abf);
    MessageBox.Show("Nach: " + selectedItem.Nach);
    MessageBox.Show("Ank: " + selectedItem.Ank);
}
```

Comment: @Nick_SMI Can you paste you XAML?

Comment: This is the code for the DataGrid: <DataGrid CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False" SelectionMode="Single" x:Name="ZeitList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,224,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="298" Width="405" ColumnWidth="Auto" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectionChanged="ZeitList_SelectionChanged"/>

Comment: @Nick_SMI So I dont understand why my code didnt work, can you explain me?

Comment: Of course I can, if I put the value (selectedItem) in a MessageBox, I get the name of the list so "Zeiten"

Comment: But It is nice that somebody help Me :)

Comment: @Nick_SMI the lists doesnt have a nave, what you get when you put selectedItem in a messagebox is the ToString of the object, the by default is the name of the class, that is the Zeiten. So my code is working properly, and this is what you need. So try to put in messagebox this: `MessageBox.Show(selectedItem.Abf)` instead `MessageBox.Show(selectedItem.ToString())`

Comment: @Nick_SMI I have changed my answer with new code, try it.